# jquery dynamic image gallery popup show all images

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

i want to create dynamic model popup so i have write below js code..but when i have click on single image then  model pop up show all images content in dynamic created div . i want same image and its content in model popup.

```js
<script>
    $("#pop").on("click", function() {
        $('#imagepreview').attr('src', $('#imageresource').attr('src'));
        $('#imagemodal').modal('show');

    });
</script>
```

```html
<div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9 col-xs-12" >

                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div id="pop">
                                            <a href="#" class="dialogpopup" style=" height: auto;width: 600px;display: -webkit-inline-box;">
                                                <div ng-repeat="Spaces in SpaceList" style="height:auto!important;display: table-caption;">
                                                    <span>{{Spaces.Name}}</span>
                                                    <img id="imageresource" src="{{Spaces.Image}}" style="width:200px; height: 200px;">
                                                    <span>{{Spaces.MaxCapacity}}</span>
                                                </div>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                         

                                        <!-- Modal -->
                                        <div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                                            <div class="modal-dialog">
                                                <div class="modal-content">
                                                    <div class="modal-header">
                                                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                                                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">{{Spaces.Name}}</h4>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="modal-body addright"  id="modelimg1" ng-repeat="Spaces in SpaceList">
                                                        <img src="{{Spaces.Image}}" id="imagepreview" style="width:400px; height: 270px;">
                                                        <p class="parapadding">
                                                            Name:{{Spaces.Name}}<br />
                                                            Description:{{Spaces.Description}}<br />
                                                            Size:{{Spaces.Size}}<br />
                                                            Capacity:{{Spaces.MaxCapacity}}<br />
                                                            Configuration:<br />

                                                        </p>
                                                    </div>


                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

ID param of any tag should be **unique**. And in your repeater you have same ids. Change it to smth like `id="{{'imagepreview' + $index}}"` and 
`ng-repeat="Spaces in SpaceList track by $index"`